# Docker placement constraints test for blank / any label

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It is legal, and documented syntax, to add a label to a docker node:

```bash
docker node update node_x --label-add "label"
```

and this will add a label that when queried, will show as an empty string:

```bash
$ docker node inspect docker-desktop --format '{{json .Spec.Labels}}'
{"label":""}
```

But, there is seemingly no valid way to make a placement constraint that can be satisfied by this label.

A different take on the problem is the need to check that a label is some value that is not blank.

For example I might want to give two nodes a label:

```bash
docker node update node_x --label-add "fruit=apple"
docker node update node_y --label-add "fruit=orange"
```

But, my attempts to check, as a placement constraint, for the existence of a blank label, fail. And, likewise, while I can check that a node is, (or is not) a specific fruit, I can't successfully test that it is [any] fruit.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.label # == or != expected
        - node.labels.label=="" # "" unexpected / '' unexpected.
        - node.labels.fruit!="" # "" unexpected / '' unexpected.
```

So, have I missed something? Is there some way to check if a label is set, without checking for a specific value. And is there any way to check for labels that are set, but to a blank value?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this ?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: Quiute sad, I saw your comments on github where the issue is pending. I ended up using `--label-add "label=true"` and use that to apply the constraint `node.labels.label=="true"`